# Definir un valor booleano que dependa de una variable en Java

Tags: android, textview, booleano, background, switch

Contexto: Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en android studio y para poder hacer que un botón switch ubicado en `MainActivity` interactúe con el background de un TextView ubicado en `Activitydos`, use SharedPreferences en el botón switch en `MainActivity`, y luego hice esto en la otra Activity:

```
poli= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Poli);
        SharedPreferences sharpol = getSharedPreferences("pol", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean polit  = sharpol.getBoolean("<nombre llave>",true);

        if(polit){
            poli.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#888888"));
        }else{
            poli.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        }
```

El problema, es que en la parte de  `Boolean polit  = sharpol.getBoolean("<nombre llave>",true);`  pide definir un valor boolean entre true o false, y esto hace que solo se pueda cumplir una de las dos opciones en el `if`, por lo que no importa si el boton switch esta activo o no, el background siempre va a ser el mismo.

Gracias por sus respuestas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El valor que defines como  `"<nombre llave>"` es el valor de la llave con la que previamente definiste el valor en la preferencia, por ejemplo si la llave con la que guardaste es "activa", lo definirìas aquì para obtener el valor que fue previamente guardado.

```
    poli= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Poli);
    SharedPreferences sharpol = getSharedPreferences("pol", MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Boolean polit  = sharpol.getBoolean("<nombre llave>",true);
    Boolean polit  = sharpol.getBoolean("activa",true);

    if(polit){
        poli.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#888888"));
    }else{
        poli.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
    }
```